# Show posts by specific term on Blogger

Tags: html, xml, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I have this code that displays blog posts by tag.

It would be possible to change the section containing the loop

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
```

by any of these variables

```
data: blog.searchUrl
date: blog.bloggerUrl
data: blog.searchLabel
data: blog.searchQuery
data: view.url
data: view.isSearch
data: view.isLabelSearch
```

Or one that can do a search for a specific term.

My goal is to show on the blog home page articles that have a certain term.

```
<b:includable id='main' var='top'>
    <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <b:if cond='data:label.name == "NOTÍCIAS"'>
    <b:include data='post' name='printPosts'/>
    </b:if>
    </b:loop>
    </b:if>
    <b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='printPosts'/>
    </b:if>
    </b:loop>
</b:includable>

<b:includable id='printPosts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
    <h2 class='date-header'>
    <data:post.dateHeader/>
    </h2>
    </b:if>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
    </b:if>
</b:includable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that using blogger codes only, because `b:loop` operator don't loop through all the posts in your blog, but only the ones in the home page which are limited.

So you have to use javascript with **blogger api** in order to show posts by tag.

Comment: Actually this code does what I want it to be shows the tag posts on the homepage

But you can only do this with the last 46 posts.

My goal was to use a different loop to increase this number of articles.